# How to make urllib.urlencode use double quotes instead of single quotes?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding urlencode.  Here is an example:

```
urllib.urlencode({"action":"task_exam_save_result","examid":5,"t2],False,2]],"spendTime":911},"submit":"true","summary":{"correct":0,"wrong":2}})
```

So, I get this:

```
examresult=%7B%27spendTime%27%3A+911%2C+%27choice%27%3A+%5B%5B1593%2C+%5B0%5D%2C+False%2C+783%5D%2C+%5B1591%2C+%5B2%5D%2C+False%2C+2%5D%5D%7D&submit=true&summary=%7B%27wrong%27%3A+2%2C+%27correct%27%3A+0%7D&taskid=10&action=task_exam_save_result&examid=5
```

Then, I copy the above string to http://tool.chinaz.com/tools/urlencode.aspx for URL decoding and get this:

```
examresult={'spendTime': 911, 'choice': [[1593, [0], false, 783],
[1591, [2], false, 2]]}&submit=true&summary={'wrong': 2, 'correct':
0}&taskid=10&action=task_exam_save_result&examid=5
```

So, every double quote becomes a single quote; why?

I want it to keep the double quotes because I have to transfer the decoded string to other programming languages, e.g. Java and Objective C, to parse, and their strings require double quotes.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please correct the argument to urllib.urlencode, as this is an invalid dict. around here: `,"t2],False,2]],"spendTime"`I suggest to correct ;-) PS: You do not get your first result from it but instead a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` rightfully pointing to the snippet the s of spendTime, as this is the first invalid character ...

Comment: Python has no idea that use used `"` in the dict literal, that information is not preserved as part of the dict. `{''.join(['a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n']): 'task...'}` would yield the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not use `urlencode here`, but convert to JSON using `json.dumps()` and then use `urlencode` or b64encode to make it safe for use in an url.

Comment: json.dumps get string; so, urlencode after that shouldn't be python's urllib.urlencode,which doesn't accept string as paramter, eh?

Comment: you seem to want to pass the string in the `examresult` parameter, so you can use `urllib.urlencode({'examResult': json.dumps({...})})`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace ALL single quotes with double quotes, then the easiest way to do this is:

```
payload = {"action":"task_exam_save_result","examid":5} 
urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
payload = payload.replace('%27', '%22')
```